# Typescrtip string literals types used in in operator

Tags: typescript

Hello Stack community,
Assume I have following string literal defined:

```
type FormConstants = 'new' | 'edit';
```

And now I'd like to check, if value `val` is equal to any of `FormConstants` defined values:

```
    function inSet(val: string): boolean {
      if ((val as FormConstants) === XXX ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

whereas `XXX` is the statement I'm looking for. Solutions as:

- `keyof FormConstants`
- `in FormConstants`
- `typeof FormConstants`

failed miserably, as each if them uses `FormConstants` as value, while `FormConstants` represents a type.

EDIT:
And I'd like to avoid for sure using `switch`/`if-elseif-else` aggregated for surestatements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types don't exist at runtime and thus any information from them can only guide compile time checking not runtime behavior. You could go for one of several options:

Use a string enum, which is a type, but also a runtime object:

```
enum FormConstants { new = 'new', edit = 'edit' }

function inSet(val: string): boolean {
    if (Object.values(FormConstants).includes(val)) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Or use a string literal array to construct a values array and derive `FormConstants` form that:

```
function stringLilteralArray<T extends string>(values: T[]) : T[] {
    return values
}
const FormConstants = stringLilteralArray(['new', 'edit']) ;
type FormConstants = typeof FormConstants[number];

function inSet(val: string): boolean {
    if (FormConstants.includes(val as FormConstants)) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

If the union of string literals is not under your control, you can construct a function to build the array of all values that ensures that the values you pass **MUST** be exactly the values in the union (the compiler will enforce this). So even if you have to duplicate the values there is no chance they will diverge:

```
type FormConstants = 'new' | 'edit';
function unionValues<T extends string>(values: { [P in T]: P}) : T[] {
    return Object.values(values);
}
const FormConstants = unionValues<FormConstants>({ new : 'new', edit :'edit' }) ;

function inSet(val: string): boolean {
    if (FormConstants.includes(val as FormConstants)) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

A variation of the above method, don't use an array, use the object keys, will surely be faster:

```
type FormConstants = 'new' | 'edit';
function unionValues<T extends string>(values: { [P in T]: true }) : typeof values {
    return values;
}
const FormConstants = unionValues<FormConstants>({ new : true, edit :true }) ;

function inSet(val: string): boolean {
    if (val in FormConstants) {
        return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Titan, many thanks as always. I understand that string literals are unavailable at run time in same way as interfaces and can not be used in object-way fashion. Your knowledge of TypeScript is well beyond expert.